# JavaScript: How do I disable the script on mobile

Tags: javascript

I only want the full-page parallax effect to be applied on screen width more than 1366.

I've tried `if(window.innerWidth >= 1366 ) {}` but then the script will have totally no effect at all when I added the script into it.

I know some people would say the script only run once on load but I did try add an resize EventListener as well, eventually it's the same where the script will have no effect after adding into something like

```
window.addEventListener("resize", () => {
    if(window.innerWidth >= 1366) {
       //Script here...
});
```

or

```
if(window.innerWidth >= 1366){
    //Script here...
}
```

My intention is to only apply the effect on screen width more than 1366 and that's why I use `if(window.innerWidth >= ) {}` , but if there are other ways to make the same result then I'm fine.

*It's different from [What is the best way to detect a mobile device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3514784/what-is-the-best-way-to-detect-a-mobile-device) because I can't define the exact width and most importantly, it's making the script not working.

Below is the script:

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    inMove: false,
    activeSection: 0,
    offsets: [],
    touchStartY: 0
  },
  methods: {
    calculateSectionOffsets() {
      let sections = document.getElementsByTagName('section');
      let length = sections.length;
      
      for(let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        let sectionOffset = sections[i].offsetTop;
        this.offsets.push(sectionOffset);
      }
    },
    handleMouseWheel: function(e) {
      
      if (e.wheelDelta < 30 && !this.inMove) {
        this.moveUp();
      } else if (e.wheelDelta > 30 && !this.inMove) {
        this.moveDown();
      }
        
      e.preventDefault();
      return false;
    },
    handleMouseWheelDOM: function(e) {
      
      if (e.detail > 0 && !this.inMove) {
        this.moveUp();
      } else if (e.detail < 0 && !this.inMove) {
        this.moveDown();
      }
      
      return false;
    },
    moveDown() {
      this.inMove = true;
      this.activeSection--;
        
      if(this.activeSection < 0) this.activeSection = this.offsets.length - 1;
        
      this.scrollToSection(this.activeSection, true);
    },
    moveUp() {
      this.inMove = true;
      this.activeSection++;
        
      if(this.activeSection > this.offsets.length - 1) this.activeSection = 0;
        
      this.scrollToSection(this.activeSection, true);
    },
    scrollToSection(id, force = false) {
      if(this.inMove && !force) return false;
      
      this.activeSection = id;
      this.inMove = true;
      
      document.getElementsByTagName('section')[id].scrollIntoView({behavior: 'smooth'});
      
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.inMove = false;
      }, 400);
      
    },
    touchStart(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      
      this.touchStartY = e.touches[0].clientY;
    },
    touchMove(e) {
      if(this.inMove) return false;
      e.preventDefault();
      
      const currentY = e.touches[0].clientY;
      
      if(this.touchStartY < currentY) {
        this.moveDown();
      } else {
        this.moveUp();
      }
      
      this.touchStartY = 0;
      return false;
    }
  },
  created() {
    this.calculateSectionOffsets();
    
    window.addEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', this.handleMouseWheelDOM);  // Mozilla Firefox
    window.addEventListener('mousewheel', this.handleMouseWheel, { passive: false }); // Other browsers
    
    window.addEventListener('touchstart', this.touchStart, { passive: false }); // mobile devices
    window.addEventListener('touchmove', this.touchMove, { passive: false }); // mobile devices
  },
  destroyed() {
    window.removeEventListener('mousewheel', this.handleMouseWheel, { passive: false });  // Other browsers
    window.removeEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', this.handleMouseWheelDOM); // Mozilla Firefox
    
    window.removeEventListener('touchstart', this.touchStart); // mobile devices
    window.removeEventListener('touchmove', this.touchMove); // mobile devices
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  color: #FFF;
  font-family: Helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
  overflow: hidden;
}

h2 {
  position: fixed;
}

.fullpage {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 6em;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0 1rem;
}

p {
  font-size: 1em;
}

.fullpage a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 600;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
  padding: 5px 10px;
  color: #FFF;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.red {
  background-color: #ab4545;
}

section.black {
  background-color: #000;
}

.blue {
  background-color: #237ad4;
}

.green {
  background-color: #68c368;
}

h1.black {
  color: #000;
}

.sections-menu {
  position: fixed;
  right: 1rem;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.sections-menu .menu-point {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: #FFF;
  display: block;
  margin: 1rem 0;
  opacity: .6;
  transition: .4s ease all;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.sections-menu .menu-point.active {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scale(1.5);
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
  h1 {
    font-size: 2.5em;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Vue.js Fullpage Scroll</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="app">
    <div class="sections-menu">
      <span
         class="menu-point"
         v-bind:class="{active: activeSection == index}"
         v-on:click="scrollToSection(index)"
         v-for="(offset, index) in offsets"
         v-bind:key="index">
      </span>
    </div>
    <section class="fullpage blue">
      <h1>Vue.js Fullpage Scroll</h1>
      <p>by <a href="https://webdeasy.de/?referer=cp-NVOEBL" target="_blank">WebDEasy</a></p>
    </section>
    <section class="fullpage black">
      <h1>Section 2</h1>
      <p>made with <a href="https://vuejs.org/" target="_blank">Vue.js</a></p>
    </section>
    <section class="fullpage red">
      <h1>Section 3</h1>
      <p>works on <b>desktop & mobile</b></p>
    </section>
    <section class="fullpage green">
      <h1>Section 4</h1>
      <p>Tutorial <a href="https://webdeasy.de/en/programming-vue-js-fullpage-scroll/?referer=cp-NVOEBL" target="_blank">here</a></p>
    </section>
  </div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.10/vue.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the best way to detect a mobile device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3514784/what-is-the-best-way-to-detect-a-mobile-device)

Comment: @MrMythical Thanks, but I've go through every solution in the articles and test it on my own, it's making the script not working at all and I can't define the exact width as well.

Comment: Can you clarify the nature of the problem - "it's not working" doesn't cover what needs to be detected and what should happen given the result of detections (e.g. replace one script with another)? Note also that zooming page content on a desktop (instead of putting on stronger reading glasses) often changes layout to that used on a mobile. So do you actually want to detect if the device is a mobile (probably not) or something else about viewing conditions or hardware controlled by the user?

Comment: @traktor Thanks for pointing out, I've edited the question to make it clearer.